# Java compile error in getting Triangular numbers sequence

Tags: java, loops, compiler-errors, while-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class TriNumbers {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int Count1=1, Count2=0;
        while (Count1>=1  Count2=0) {
            System.out.println(Count2+=Count1+"");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the compiler-error. Also when asking questions, it is best to include some context and the actual question in your post, not just a block of code.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `&&` in between two comparisons:

```
Count1>=1  Count2=0
```

should be

```
Count1>=1  && Count2=0
```

Also you are using single `=` which is for assignment. Use `==` for comparison. So finally this should be your condition:

```
while (Count1>=1  && Count2==0)
```

**Note:** You may have to replace `&&` with some other operator(||, != etc). I just used it for example.

Comment: @Aniket yeah i realized just after posting the answer. So edited it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`while(Count1>=1 Count2 = 0)` <- here is the error.. makes no sense absolutely.

What are you trying to do?